# MySQL error when running "rake db:migrate"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Does anybody have suggestions about how to move forward with fixing this error?

```
Tipsy:todoodly admin$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried reinstalling MySQL with the .dmg file, but still running into problems.

Also tried this after browsing online, but still doesn't work

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Comment: Did you install mysql from a .dmg file ?

Comment: I originally installed with homebrew, but was running into issues, so uninstalled and reinstalled via this tutorial http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2011/02/10/mac-os-x-mysql-install/

Comment: Well Mac os comes with mysql preinstalled.

Comment: @n0idea it doesn't anymore, actually.  Now it comes with Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure though if it will work but paste this in the terminal:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=”$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib/”
```